# How does one change the top number in a summation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

Sorry I do not know the correct term (I am guessing "upper limit"). Here is what I mean.
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\color{red}{17}}\frac{2i}{i+3}$$
The $17$ is what I am talking about as "the top number". Is there a way to change it to something like $5$?
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\color{red}{17}}\frac{2i}{i+3}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\color{green}{5}} \ \ \ \ \ \text{<--- What goes over there?}$$
I could not find any solution online, so I suspect that it is impossible to do so.

Comment: It is *possible*, but nothing useful springs to mind in this case.

Comment: @AndréNicolas If it is possible, but not for every case, can you please show me a case where it is possible, and how to change the "top number" in that case

Comment: @JChau it is possible certainly. For instance $$\sum_{i=0}^{10} i = \sum_{i=1}^{11} (i-1)$$ I admit this isn't creative, but the basic idea is that the sum stays the same, we just rewrite it in a different form. May I ask why you are asking for this case in particular?

Comment: My comment was not serious. But for example, your sum is $\sum_{i=1}^{5} f(i)$, where $f(i)=\sum_{j=1}^{17} \frac{1}{5}\cdot \frac{2j}{j+3}$. Technically correct, but useless.

Comment: @Sabyasachi I am just curious... I have been taught how to change the "bottom number", but not the top

Comment: @JChau as long as your $\sum$ represents the same sum, you can change it however you want. I doubt there is a nice way to sum the series in question though.

Comment: @JChau Are you asking us to keep the general thing inside the summation the same or as same as we possibly can?